# Concatenating selectors that include variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pretty confident that this can be done but my efforts so far have failed. I have a loop generated series of divs that have id=x0, x1, x2 etc.... Depending on context the html of one or more div(s) will be reset. In the case where two divs will have the same value, and the id is a known number I would easily do:

```
$('#x3, #x7').html('new value');
```

How to set this when the id number is a variable? I first tried:

```
$('#x'+(location-2), '#x'+(location+3)).html('new value'); // doesn't throw a console error  
// but doesn't work
```

I tried numerous permutations involving quotes, escaped quotes, brackets {}, [], () - in combination with quotes, etc. etc. hair pulling etc.

To keep the project moving I am declaring multiple replacements which is no great extra load but it would be tidier to have a single call -- and, I always look to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a common class would be a better solution to this, but to answer your question, you didn't concatenate properly:

```
$('#x' + (location-2) + ', #x' + (location+3)).html('new value');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/1x63k85e/)**

And you also may run into issues using `location` as a variable name as it's a [property of the Window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Comment: I tested and it works. thanks. I have to wait a few minutes to accept you answer

Comment: yes, location is not good. Also a common class would replace all instances. I need to be quite selective.

Comment: Ah, then you can skip the class and stick with IDs.

Comment: finally got your answer selected -- and +1 for your specifics, fiddle and promptness. And thank to all the other replies. This forum rocks.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an array of selectors and then join them:

```js
var selectors = [
    '#x' + (location - 2),
    '#x' + (location + 3)
];

var jointSelector = selectors.join(',');
```

Comment: For me the most clean solution. I would do it that way!

Answer (score 0):

you miss the apostrophe

```
$("#x"+(location-2)+",#x"+(location+3)).html('new value')
```

Answer (score 0):

After concation it should look like **'#x3, #x7'**. But here you are not concating the comma. That is the mistake you are doing.

```
 $('#x' + (location-2) + ', #x' + (location+3)).html('new value');
```